# Can NPOI set a password to protect the whole workbook?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

I use NPOI to create excel file in c# .Net Framework project.
I only can find a method to set password to protect sheet before modify.
But my requirement is to protect the whole workbook when user open the file.
If don't have correct password can't open the file.
thank you!